# ¿Cómo podemos traducir "That's really what it's all about" al castellano?

Tags: traducción, expresiones, español-neutral, solicitud-de-modismo

Traduciendo [Thanking users who answered my question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17878/209901) me encuentro con el párrafo final de Jeff Atwood, el fundador de Stack Exchange:

> Alternately, just "pay it forward" and answer another programmer's question. **That's really what it's all about.**

Viene a decir que en la filosofía de este sitio consiste en agradecer las respuestas que recibas siguiendo la cadena de favores y respondiendo a la pregunta que otro tenga.

La parte de "pay it forward" la traduje efetivamente como *cadena de favores* y me convence bastante, supongo que por influencia de la traducción de la película [*Pay it forward*](http://www.filmaffinity.com/es/film371351.html) (2000) que en España nombramos así, *Cadena de favores*. El resto lo escribo así:

> Alternativamente, simplemente sigue con la "cadena de favores" y responde otra pregunta de otro programador. **Es de lo que trata todo esto.**

Pero de todos modos "es de lo que trata todo esto" me parece algo forzado y pienso que se os puede ocurrir algo más idiomático. Se me ocurre también ***De eso se trata, al fin y al cabo***. ¿Alguien tiene alguna idea? Lo mismo aplica a lo de *pay it forward*, si consideráis que hay expresiones más acertadas.

Nótese que la traducción es para Stack Overflow en español, por lo que debe ser español neutral.

Comment: Yo probablemente lo habría traducido como «es así de simple/sencillo», no sé si lo considerarías como con demasiada licencia.

Comment: @guifa dicen que _lo bueno si breve, dos veces bueno_. Me parece muy buena sugerencia, gracias.

Comment: tal vez se podría añadir «de verdad»: *De verdad, es así de sencillo*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te pongo mi opción (si no es español neutro, pido disculpas):

> Alternativamente, puedes devolver el favor a la comunidad respondiendo a una pregunta de cualquier otro programador. A fin de cuentas, de eso trata este sitio.

Comentarios:

- Iba a poner simplemente "devolver el favor", pero añadí "a la comunidad" por si se entendía que había que devolver el favor a la misma persona que te respondió. Aunque para eso digo "de cualquier otro programador", así que bien se puede eliminar lo de "a la comunidad".
- Puedes cambiar "alternativamente" por "otra opción", que queda más natural.
- Iba a usar el verbo *ir* ("de eso va este sitio"), pero curiosamente el verbo *ir* [no tiene una acepción para ese significado](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20219/12637), aunque se puede usar de forma coloquial. Tampoco sé si quedaría demasiado localizado así.
- Si quieres mantener el concepto de "cadena de favores" a toda costa, yo pondría "puedes continuar la cadena y responder...". Se entiende que es una cadena de favores, en este caso no creo que haga falta especificarlo.
- No creo necesario traducir el "just" a toda costa, muchas veces las frases quedan mejor si no se traduce.

Ya centrándonos en la frase que te preocupa, de tus opciones la mejor me parece la de "de eso se trata, al fin y al cabo". Creo que es la que mejor recoge la idea original. Yo he añadido "este sitio" por si quedaba algún resquicio de duda acerca de a qué se refería la frase.

Así que, teniendo en cuenta lo hablado, la versión más corta (y tal vez natural a la par que coloquial) sería:

> Otra opción es devolver el favor respondiendo preguntas de otros programadores. De eso va el sitio, a fin de cuentas.

Comment: Mira por dónde, se me acaba de ocurrir un juego que podríamos aplicar aquí, al estilo de [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/): se propone una traducción y gana aquella que mantenga todo el sentido original usando el menor número de letras posible. :-)

Comment: Me gusta la circularidad de _devolver a la comunidad_ en lugar de la cadena de favores, que es más lineal. En cuanto al _just_, creo que poniéndolo mantenemos el tono original de "eh, tranqui, simplemente haz esto, tampoco te preocupes".

Comment: ¡Empecemos con este tipo de Code Golf! Gran idea :)

Comment: @fedorqui ¿hace una etiqueta "translation-golf"? :-D

Comment: Por mí, adelante. Definimos unas reglas básicas y empezamos :)

Comment: @fedorqui [Planteado en meta](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2591/12637).