# Si digo "la película va de un tío que...", ¿qué acepción del verbo "ir" estoy usando?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, definiciones, significado

En [mi respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20210/12637) a [¿Cómo podemos traducir "That's really what it's all about" al castellano?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20209/12637) me he dado cuenta de que muchas veces uso el verbo ir en frases como:

- La película va de un tío que...
- De eso va este sitio, a fin de cuentas.

Entiendo que se usa como sinónimo de "tratar", ya que ambas frases quedan igual usando este verbo, pero el caso es que entre las definiciones del verbo *[ir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=M5ucdgy)* no me queda claro qué acepción es la que encaja en este tipo de frases. ¿Cuál de todas podría ser? Y como extra: ¿se entiende esta construcción en Hispanoamérica?

Comment: Seguramente sería esta ¿no?: **8.** *intr.* Considerar las cosas por un aspecto especial o dirigirlas a un fin determinado. *Si por honestidad va, ¿qué cosa más honesta que la virtud? Ahora va de veras.*

Comment: @guifa esa es la que proponía yo en la otra respuesta, pero no lo tenía claro, y los ejemplos de la RAE no me parecían tener el mismo sentido que los míos. Plantéalo en todo caso como respuesta, y lo debatimos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tal y como proponía guifa coincidiendo conmigo, podría parecer que la acepción que se usa es la siguiente:

> 8. intr. Considerar las cosas por un aspecto especial o dirigirlas a un fin determinado. *Si por honestidad va, ¿qué cosa más honesta que la virtud? Ahora va de veras.*

Sin embargo, no me terminaba de encajar con la acepción buscada en el ejemplo de la pregunta, dado que en la frase "la película va de...", el verbo *ir* no se usa para dirigir nada a ningún fin, ni considera algo por un aspecto concreto. Simplemente se usa como sinónimo de "[tratar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=aX264Ov)" en el sentido de "conferir, discurrir o disputar de palabra o por escrito sobre un asunto".

El caso es que le he preguntado a la RAE, y me han respondido [lo siguiente](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/844867776565202944):

> Es un uso coloquial y, en efecto, no aparece en el DLE la acepción correspondiente.

Por lo tanto, hice bien en desconfiar.

Comment: Pues parece que hace más de cinco años que se usa, de acuerdo con [¿Durante cuántos años debe aparecer una palabra en textos escritos para que la RAE la recoja en el diccionario?](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18511/1674) ya podría ir incluyéndolo.

Comment: @fedorqui propuesta realizada, se pueden hacer propuestas mediante [este formulario](http://www.rae.es/formulario/unidrae).

Answer (score 3):

Es la acepción nº 31 de [**ir**](https://dle.rae.es/ir) de DLE:

> 31. intr. coloq. Dicho de un libro, de una película, de una conversación, etc.: Tratar de un tema determinado. *¿DE qué va esa novela?*

Comment: Parece que la acepción ha sido añadida en la edición de 2022: https://dle.rae.es/contenido/actualizaci%C3%B3n-2022

Answer (score 2):

Respondiendo a la parte "extra" de la pregunta, me gustaría que otros hispanoparlantes americanos diesen su testimonio, pero ni en Argentina ni en mi limitada exposición a otros dialectos latinoamericanos he oído nunca esta construcción. Lo que no quita que sea inmediatamente comprensible por el contexto.

Se me antoja que puede haber una relación con la construcción (recogida como expresión fija en el DRAE) *[¿a qué vino eso?](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bXkUiz2)*. En Argentina es común escuchar *¿A qué vino eso?* (empleado exactamente en las circunstancias en que un angloparlante preguntaría *What was that about?*) y la negativa *No sé a qué vino eso* (o *No sé a qué viene lo que estás diciendo* y similares).

Comment: ¡Gracias por responder a la parte extra! En España también se usa la expresión que comentas, solo que (como ya imaginarás), aquí se usa la variante _¿A qué ha venido eso?_ cambiando el tiempo verbal.

Comment: En Chile diría que se entiende por el contexto pero no se usa. En mi experiencia se utiliza "se trata de".