# Significado de "me va" en canción de Julio Iglesias

Tags: verbos, significado, españa, letras-de-canciones

Esta es una extensión de la [pregunta de Carlos Alejo sobre "la película va de un tío..."](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20211/6915). Me he dado cuenta de que conozco la canción desde niño y nunca me había preguntado acerca del significado exacto de la letra. El sentido se entiende, no hay problema, pero en Chile y probablemente en Latinoamérica no usamos el verbo "ir" como lo usan en España.

¿Qué acepción del verbo "ir" se usa acá, y cómo podríamos "traducir" este verso a un español más estándar?

> Me va la vida, me va la gente de aquí y de allá...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pues yo diría que podría ser esta:

> 2. intr. Dicho de una cosa: Sentar bien o mal a algo o a alguien. *Una blusa negra no le va a esa falda.*

El ejemplo que indica tal vez no sea exactamente el mismo (dado que el sujeto pasa de ser una cosa a una persona en tu caso), pero creo que cuando dices que "algo te va" es porque te sienta bien, es decir, que te gusta el efecto que eso produce en ti.

En España tenemos un ejemplo muy conocido y publicitario: una marca de productos lácteos llamada Puleva (acrónimo de *PUra LEche de VAca*, por si alguien no lo sabía) anuncia sus batidos con una cancioncita tal que así:

> Batidos Puleva, le va, le va, le va.

Es decir, los batidos "le van" al que los toma (le sientan bien). Si quieres un ejemplo en español neutro, creo que podría ser simplemente:

> Me gusta la vida, me gusta la gente de aquí y de allá...

En todo caso no es exactamente lo mismo, porque si digo "me va", lo que me gusta no es la cosa en sí, sino el efecto que produce en ti. Es una diferencia sutil. Ejemplo: si dices que "la falda le va a la blusa" no quieres decir que te guste la falda o la blusa, sino la combinación de ambas.

Comment: Yo si que he interpretado siempre el "me va" como dos posibles significados, que son como bien dices "quedar/sentar bien" y "gustar", por lo que no estoy completamente de acuerdo con tu último párrafo. Opino que tu último ejemplo significa exactamente lo mismo que la canción, sin lugar a sutilezas. Supongo que es cuestión de a lo que estemos cada uno acostumbrados a escuchar.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que, aplicado a personas, el significado es muy parecido a "caer bien". Aplicado a cosas, ese "caer bien" ya no cae tan bien... La frase en cuestión quizás se "traduciría" como:

> Me gusta la vida, me cae bien la gente de aquí y de allá...

Pero se rompe el paralelismo... :(

Otra posible "traducción" en otros contextos sería "quedar(le) bien":

> Esta camisa no me va   ----> esta camisa no me queda bien